# Criar uma lista de imagens no ListView usando foreach

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, windows

tenho um form com um ListView puxando informaçoes do banco como ex: Nome, porem quero que traga tambem uma imagem para estar junto com a descrição, oque eu quero fazer na verdade e uma tela com controle de mesas porem nao estou conseguindo.
[esse e meu codigo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF7JP.png)

[como exemplo eu quero que fique dessa forma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfcmc.png)

Comment: Olá! Evite postar prints de código. Sempre prefira postar código no formato texto, devidamente formatado como código. Isso aumenta suas chances de obter a ajuda solicitada.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Considerando que você vinculou o Listview ao imagelist através da propriedade ListView.LargImageList, adicione abaixo da criação do novo item o indice ImageIndex referenciando a imagem do ImageList.

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(c.nome);

// adicione essa linha.
item.ImageIndex = 0 ;/* aqui você atribui o indice em relação com a 
                         imagem no ImageList, 0,1,2,3 conforme a
                         sequência das imagens */
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela resposta muito grato me ajudou muito aqui.

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa adicionar seu ImageList no seu ListView. Algo como:

```
listView1.LargeImageList = imageList;
```

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo, me ajudou bastante  com essa dica.